# Creating a multiprocess cache in Elixir

Tags: erlang, elixir

I'm reading `7 concurrency models in 7 weeks` and the author asks to implement

> cache that distributes cache entries across multiple actors according
>   to a hash function. Create a supervisor that starts multiple cache
>   actors and routes incoming messages to the appropriate cache worker.
>   What action should this supervisor take if one of the cache workers
>   fails?

```
defmodule CacheSupervisor do
  def start(number_of_caches) do
    spawn(__MODULE__, :init, [number_of_caches])
  end

  def init(number_of_caches) do
    Process.flag(:trap_exit, true)

    pids = Enum.into(Enum.map(0..number_of_caches-1, fn(id) ->
                                         {id, Cache.start}
                                     end), %{})

    loop(pids, number_of_caches)
  end

  def loop(pids, number_of_caches) do
    receive do
        {:put, url, page} -> send(compute_cache_pid(pids, url, number_of_caches), {:put, url, page})
                            loop(pids, number_of_caches)
        {:get, sender, ref, url} -> send(compute_cache_pid(pids, url, number_of_caches), {:get, sender, ref, url})
                                    loop(pids, number_of_caches)
        {:EXIT, pid, reason} -> IO.puts("Cache #{pid} failed with reason #{inspect reason} - restarting it")
                                loop(repair(pids, pid), number_of_caches)
    end
  end

  def restart(pids, pid) do
    #not clear how to repair, since we don't know the index of the failed process
  end

  def compute_cache_pid(pids, url, number_of_caches) do
    pids[rem(:erlang.phash2(url), number_of_caches)]
  end
end
```

When a process fails, supervisor only get its `pid`. Using just pid, I can't understand which bucket needs a new process. I probably could create a second map `pid -> bucket_index`, but it seems ugly.

Can I somehow attach additional attributes when I spawn a process? Can I read those attributes when process exits?

What would be the best way to solve it (without OTP)?

This implementation also makes supervisor too "smart". As I understand supervisors should be simple and only care about restarting failed processes.

I'm not sure how to separate restarting and routing logic into 2 separate processes: when supervisor restarts some process, router should be aware of it and have up-to-date `pids`.

Comment: I believe two maps is the recommended way. An example in "Designing for Scalability with Erlang/OTP" stores a similar pid <=> integer mapping in two ETS tables named `msisdn2pid` and `pid2msisdn` (page 45 if you have a copy).

Comment: Well, as it is tagget as Erlang also, I would say this ad-hock superviosor looks ugly and you should consider fancy erlang `supervisor` that will do the job for you. Accroding to naming, I think simple `register(list_to_atom(integer_to_list(Id))` is the best point to start